# Why is the Django database cache not shared across multiple threads?

Tags: django, django-caching

It seems each thread maintains its separate cache. Should I just use my own Django object to have a Database cache shared by multiple threads? What are the negatives to doing this?

The problem I am facing is this:

1. I am using the database cache
2. I save to the cache while processing a request
3. I retrieve from the cache while processing the next request

I expect it to be in the cache but it is not there. By printing the thread  ident, I see it is a different thread. The same thread gets a cache hit but a different thread gets a cache miss.

I don't expect this to happen with the database cache backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is only true if you use the locmem cache backend. Which you should not do in production; use a proper cache, whether it is the filesystem or db caches, or a dedicated cache backend like memcached or redis.

Comment: From the documentation: "To provide thread-safety, a different instance of the cache backend will be returned for each thread." I verified this to be true in practice during my debugging.

Comment: Yes, but that didn't seem to be what you were asking. Each instance would normally point to the same store, so that they would have access to the same data.

Comment: Do I have to use locks to read and write using the database cache? I am not doing that yet. Could that be my problem?

Comment: I don't even know what your problem is. What issue are you having? And what threads do you have in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611737/django-global-data-for-threads seems to agree with you

Comment: I have expanded my question with more background.